# How do I package and distribute my WordPress plugin via git?

Tags: testing, git, composer

I wrote a custom plugin for saving an uploaded .xlsx file to a .csv file. The code required an outside library and I used composer to install the code into my plugin's directory. So now I have this `composer.json` file in my plugin directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.27"
    }
}
```

I also used wp-cli to generate the skeleton for the plugin. This added some files and directories for testing the plugin like `bin`, `tests` and `phpunit.xml.dist`. I haven't written any tests for the plugin yet though I may write some after I refamiliarize myself with writing tests for WordPress (it's been a while).

So I now want to push the module out from my devel machine and try it out on a staging server. WordPress/PHP development is not something I do that often. So I'm a little uncertain on how to accomplish. My specific questions are:

1. What should I put in my .gitignore file?
2. Am I even using composer properly? Does the `vendor` directory and `composer.json` file even belong in the plugin directory? This doesn't feel right to me but I'm not very familiar with composer and how it is intended to be used.
3. Is there some mechanism for automating the installation of the library file provided by composer on the staging server? Or is that just something I have to take care of myself? I don't think the staging server even has composer installed on it.

Hopefully these are good questions and I'm not out to lunch. If I am or if there is anything else I need to consider, I'd appreciate a clue.

Comment: generally there's a one question per question rule here, bundling questions can severely reduce your chances of an answer as any answer has to answer _all_ of the questions, and you need to be able to mark an answer as the factually correct answer. Remember this is not a forum/messageboard, it's a Q&A site!

Comment: Otherwise, the answer to almost all the questions is "it depends", they're all incredibly subjective. It can go in your `vendor` folder, or not, or elsewhere, the code is not supposed to care where the `vendor` folder lives that's what the autoloaders is for. Also question 3 does not have an answer, there is no golden path to follow, just lots of competing approaches with various tradeoffs ( Q3 might be closed as off-topic here as there's no way to mark an answer as the factually correct answer ).

Comment: Ok, thanks. From what little I've read so far, I'm basically on the right track. I guess I'll just give it my best shot and see what I can improve if I run into any complications. Thanks.

Comment: note that if you can't run things on your server and want it as a standalone plugin that just uses composer for development, then you'll need to commit your built assets and vendor folder into a release package on github, or do it on the remote server, or commit it all to git

Comment: Ah, good tip. That beats keeping track of one more thing to manage on the server.